# why recycler view not show when call from API

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to show information that call from API to recycler view in fragment, but the recycler view doesnt show the information. The Api show GET method and need to display the list in Recycler View.

This is my Model

```
public class PhoneModel {

    public PhoneModel() {
    }

   private int amount;
   private String amount_display;

   public int getAmount() {
       return amount;
   }

   public void setAmount(int amount) {
       this.amount = amount;
   }

   public String getAmount_display() {
       return amount_display;
   }

   public void setAmount_display(String amount_display) {
       this.amount_display = amount_display;
   }
}
```

This is my Adapter. i just want to show one information only in Recycler View.

```
public class PhoneAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhoneAdapter.PhoneViewHolder> {

   private ArrayList<PhoneModel> listItems;
   private Context context;
   LayoutInflater inflater;

   public PhoneAdapter(Context context) {
       this.listItems = new ArrayList<>();
       this.context = context;
       inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   }

   @Override
   public PhoneViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View v = inflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.view_holder_phone,parent,false);
       return new PhoneViewHolder(v);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(PhoneViewHolder holder, int position) {

       holder.test.setText(listItems.get(position).getAmount_display());
   }


   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return listItems.size();
   }

   public void add(PhoneModel model) {
      listItems.add(model);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   public void clear() {
       listItems.clear();
       notifyDataSetChanged();
   }


public class PhoneViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView test;
    private TextView currentBal;

    public PhoneViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        test = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_deposit);
        currentBal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_bal);

    }
   }
}
```

This is my Activity which i connect with Phone Model and Phone Adapter.

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

private final static String TAG = HistoryFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private PhoneAdapter phoneAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

public HistoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_history);
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    phoneAdapter = new PhoneAdapter(getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(phoneAdapter);

    phoneHistory();

    return view;
}

private void phoneHistory(){

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            ServerApi.URL_PHONE,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

                    if(response != null) {

                        try {
                            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                            PhoneModel phoneModel = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getJSONObject("value").toString(), PhoneModel.class);
                            phoneAdapter.add(phoneModel);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
    ) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return headers;
        }

    };

    Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(request);
}


}
```

Comment: are u sure u r getting data from api response?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);



recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_history);
LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),
        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);   

 phoneHistory(); 

phoneAdapter = new PhoneAdapter(getContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(phoneAdapter);



return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You getting empty data because in adapter constructor you creating new `arraylist()`.

Change this:

```
public PhoneAdapter(Context context) {
    this.listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

To

```
public PhoneAdapter(Context context,Arraylist list) {
    this.listItems = list;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

also change in fragment:

```
phoneAdapter = new PhoneAdapter(getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(phoneAdapter,list);
```

and in `phoneHistory()` method

```
if(response != null) {

     try {
           jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

         PhoneModel phoneModel = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getJSONObject("value").toString(), PhoneModel.class);
         phoneModel .add(phoneModel);
         list.add(phoneModel )
         phoneAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
         } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
     }
```

Hope it will help you!!